# Basic probability with given relative frequency

Tags: probability

In a textbook on elementary probability I came across this exercise:

> In a big school $30 \%$ of the students wear glasses. 20 students are
>   randomly chosen and have to undergo an eye exam. What's the
>   probability that the first two chosen students wear glasses?

According to the answer in the textbook the probability is $0.09$ but I can't figure out why. My idea would be that the probability that the first student wears glasses is $\frac{0.3n}{n}$ (where $n$ is the total amount of students) and the probability that the second stundent wears glasses is $\frac{0.3n-1}{n-1}$. Then the total probability is $\frac{0.09n-0.03}{n-1}$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The problem specified a "big" school.  Thus, we are free to assume that $n$ is very large.  Your expression approaches $.09$ when $n$ is large.

Comment: Note:  the numerator of your expression should read $.09n-.3$.  Doesn't change the limit.

Comment: @lulu What would be the correct expression? My numerator is $0.09n-0.03$? Thanks for your comment!

Comment: You have a $.03$ where you should have a $.3$.

Comment: @lulu Oh right, thanks!